# Understanding what a memory dump/snapshot/state is

Tags: process, state, snapshot, dump

I have a game in which there is a character who can walk, run, and jump. He has health. I can save the state of the game (process) - take a snapshot, dump using a special tool. Then walk around, run, reduce the amount of health and load the dump into the process memory and eventually get the original coordinates and the initial amount of health (which was at the time the dump was created).

Can I say that a snapshot or memory dump is the bytes that were stored at the time the snapshot was created in the virtual address space (in the heap, code segment, data segment, BSS segment, stack and in the area for loaded libraries see the image below)?[image]

If so, then I can read the bytes in the memory addresses and write these bytes and the corresponding memory addresses to a file, and then, when I need to, using a loop or something like that, write these bytes to the required addresses back to the game process.